# How to remove double underline during typing in Japanese language in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using [Fleather](https://pub.dev/packages/fleather) package in my project. This issue is generated in MacBook chrome browser also if am using normal flutter Textfield then still generate same issue with  double underline

[image]

I want to single underline with suggestions during typing

[image]